# Firebase Crashlytics not showing up line of crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am using crashlytics in my app since it was part of Fabric. I would see the crash line and Class name. But now in Firebase, I don't see the line number causing the crash.

Here is the crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Haraj                          0x100c1eb00 specialized GQLHelper.submitPost(post:onFinish:) + 4313017088 (<compiler-generated>:4313017088)
1  Haraj                          0x100bb900c HJAdDetailsViewController.submitPost() + 4312600588 (<compiler-generated>:4312600588)
2  Haraj                          0x100bbcc94 partial apply for closure #1 in HJAdDetailsViewController.setupPopOver() + 4312616084 (<compiler-generated>:4312616084)
3  Haraj                          0x100c303f8 @objc HJAgreementsView.acceptButtonPressed(_:) + 4313089016
4  UIKitCore                      0x1bef53a44 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
5  UIKitCore                      0x1be9976d0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 240
6  UIKitCore                      0x1be997a34 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 408
7  UIKitCore                      0x1be996a50 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 520
8  UIKitCore                      0x1bef8cd68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2324
9  UIKitCore                      0x1bef8e0a8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3352
10 UIKitCore                      0x1bef6aae8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 336
11 UIKitCore                      0x1befe223c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 5880
12 UIKitCore                      0x1befe4798 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4924
13 UIKitCore                      0x1befe4ae4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5768
14 UIKitCore                      0x1befdd60c __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 108
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1baec27e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1baec2738 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1baec1ed0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1baebd01c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1baebc8bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
20 GraphicsServices               0x1c4d28328 GSEventRunModal + 104
21 UIKitCore                      0x1bef526d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
22 Haraj                          0x100a54ad8 main + 15 (main.m:15)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x1bad47460 start + 4
```

In here the crash seems to be coming from `GQLHelper.submitPost(post:onFinish:)` but the line number is invalid.

Any help? Has something got changed while moving from Fabric to Firebase?

In firebase, I don't see missing `dSYMs` for this particular release version.

Comment: same happens with me. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @sp309 No solution so far. Google has ruined Crashlytics. Try Sentry.

Comment: did you get any fix for this. I am facing this issue currently. let me know